# nhibernate generating 2 different queries for the same source on 2 different machines

Tags: .net, sql, nhibernate, criteria

Hi
I have the same code and the same hbms running on two different machines each with nhibernate 3  (everything is on a source repository and the latest verions are checked out from there) and nhibernate generates different sql queries on each of the machines

```
SearchResult<Contact> searchResult = new SearchResult<Contact>();
            RepositoryLink<Contact> link = new RepositoryLink<Contact>();


                ICriteria icriteria = null;
                var clientCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Contact>("c")
                                        .CreateCriteria("ContactRoles","cr", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
                                        .CreateCriteria("AclRole", "ar" ,NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
                                        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ar.RoleName", RoleCode.Client));


            foreach (var keyValuePair in searchCriteria)
            {
                switch (keyValuePair.Key)
                {
                    case SearchClientCriterion.Branch:
                        clientCriteria.CreateCriteria("c.BuEntries", "be" , NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
                            .CreateCriteria("be.BuLevel","bl", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
                            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("bl.LevelNo", keyValuePair.Value));
                        break;
                    case SearchClientCriterion.City:
                        clientCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("c.City", keyValuePair.Value));
                        break;
                    case SearchClientCriterion.ClientID:
                        clientCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("c.ID", keyValuePair.Value));
                        break;
                    case SearchClientCriterion.DOB:
                        break;
                    case SearchClientCriterion.FirstName:
                        clientCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Like("c.FirstName", keyValuePair.Value,MatchMode.Anywhere));
                        break;
                    case SearchClientCriterion.LastName:
                        clientCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Like("c.LastName", keyValuePair.Value, MatchMode.Anywhere));
                        break;
                    case SearchClientCriterion.State:
                        clientCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("c.StateId", keyValuePair.Value));
                        break;
                }
            }

            if(buLevel > 0)
                clientCriteria.CreateCriteria("c.BuEntries", "be", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
                        .CreateCriteria("be.BuLevel", "bl", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
                        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("bl.LevelNo", buLevel));


            var clientCountCriteria = (ICriteria)clientCriteria.GetExecutableCriteria(link.Session).Clone();
            searchResult.Count = clientCountCriteria.SetProjection(Projections.CountDistinct("c.ID")).UniqueResult<int>();


            icriteria = clientCriteria.GetExecutableCriteria(link.Session);
            searchResult.Data = icriteria.SetFirstResult((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).SetMaxResults(pageSize).List<Contact>();
```

this is the criteria
this generates:

```
SELECT count(distinct this_.contactkey) as y0_
FROM   [Contact] this_
       inner join [ContactRole] cr1_
         on this_.contactkey = cr1_.contactkey
       inner join [AclRole] ar2_
         on cr1_.rolekey = ar2_.rolekey
WHERE  ar2_.rolename = 'C' /* @p0 */
       and this_.firstname like '%alex%' /* @p1 */
```

on one machine and

```
SELECT count(distinct this_.contactkey) as y0_
FROM   [Contact] this_
       left outer join [ContactRole] contactrol1_
         on this_.contactkey = contactrol1_.contactkey
       left outer join [AclRole] aclrole2_
         on contactrol1_.rolekey = aclrole2_.rolekey
WHERE  this_.username like '%alex%' /* @p0 */
       and not (aclrole2_.rolename = 'C' /* @p1 */)
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Are both versions pointing to the same database, also are the session factory configuration the same for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I recreated the entire database. Deleted everything. Recreated it.
Checked out everything again and now it worked.

Comment: Well problem solved :-) But I would have liked to know what was the real issue.

Comment: @Tomas I would have liked that to

Answer (score 0):

You don't happen to have a difference in the config:
A difference in

```
            <property name="use_outer_join">true</property>
```

in the session factory may be the cause of your issue.

Comment: I have one web service calling another web service in the caller web service this property is indeed there I deleted it anyway. In the called web service this property is not there but that is the web service that generates the 2 queries above. I don't see how the setting in the first service could affect the second one.

Comment: @Para You mentioned 2 different machines generating the query. Are there any missmatch between the config on those two?

Comment: For me, property use_outer_join in NH 3.2 generates error, is deprecated-obsolete